# ngx-translate is not working for lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, localization, ngx-translate

I want to implement **ngx-translate** in angular 5 project lazy loaded module wise its working for only parent module but not works in my child module so please suggest better solution.

I write my code for app module .

and i am using @ngx-translate/core and @ngx-translate/http-loader

app.module.ts

```
 TranslateModule.forRoot({
      @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    LayoutModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpModule, ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: false }
    ),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })

export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/app/', '.json');

}
```

child.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [

    RouterModule,
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    GridModule,
    DropDownsModule,
    FormsModule,
    ExcelModule,
    ControlMessagesModule, ReactiveFormsModule,    
    TranslateModule.forChild({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (AdminTranslateLoader),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      },
      isolate: true
    })

  ],

export function AdminTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/admin/', '.json');
}
```

Comment: Try using the same path `'./assets/i18n/app/'` for both modules and see if it works. I am using same file across different modules and it is working fine to me

Comment: My requirement is store translation in different json file like module wise and store specific translation in specific file example if admin module loaded then only admin/en-json will be load and only admin translation should be load for translation

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem, where I was calling **TranslateModule.forRoot()** in a **SharedModule**:

```
TranslateModule.forRoot({
    loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
    }
})
```

This *SharedModule* is imported by all my other *lazy-loaded* modules.
I have a **menu-bar** child component with a button to switch language. This component gets the **TranslateService** via injection in the usual way of the constructor:

```
constructor(private translate: TranslateService) { }
```

### The Problem

Calling `TranslateService.use('[LANG-CODE]')` does change the translation in my menu-bar component. But it didn't change the translation for any other child components.

### This worked for me

I found this (quite old) issue on github that basically says we shouldn't be calling *TranslateModule.forRoot()* in a **SharedModule**.

[github issue - TranslateModule.forRoot should not be put in SharedModule](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/209)

So I moved the `TranslateModule.forRoot()` into the `AppModule` as suggested, and export the `TranslateModule`. Then I import and export `TranslateModule` in my `SharedModule`.

After doing this, calling `TranslateService.use()` translates the texts for other child components too, not just the one that is calling the function (`menu-bar` in my case)

Hopefully anyone else with a similar problem will find this useful.

Comment: after 3 hours i could fix the issue. Thanks !

Answer (score 7):

I had same problem with my `Angular 12` project as well.

Configured the project as:

1. Added `TranslateModule.forRoot()` in `app.module.ts` like

```
export function httpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient){
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    TranslateModule.forRoot(
      {
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: httpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }
    ),
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

2. Imported and Exported `TranslateModule` in my `SharedModule`.

```
import { NgModule, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TranslateModule
  ],
  exports: [
    TranslateModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

3. Imported the `SharedModule` in Lazy Loaded Component Module.
4. It will works smoothly.

Comment: Can you add shared module code as well.

Comment: added shared module code as well

Comment: Ok understood thanks

Comment: This is only one solution, which works for me on the whole Internet. I don't even have a SharedModule, just a simple child module. I can now only wonder what is this `forChild()` needed for, when it's not needed at all.

Answer (score 3):

Shared module concept is anyway a proper solution , but calling in child module and changing `forChild()` worked for me in angular 12.

```
TranslateModule.forChild({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateModule,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a bug ... workaround is to make sure the language is reinitialized on module load. To do this, i added this constructor to all my lazy loaded modules:

```
constructor(protected translateService: TranslateService) {
   const currentLang = translateService.currentLang;
   translateService.currentLang = '';
   translateService.use(currentLang);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me in Angular 9.

Note: Please replace 'moduleName' with your application module name.

For lazy loaded modules you can place your lang files in different folders module wise and refer them from your component like this.

```
export function moduleNameHttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, '/assets/i18n/moduleName/', 
'.json');
}
```

and you can add the below code to imports in your lazy loaded module i.e moduleName.module.ts file.

```
    TranslateModule.forChild({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: moduleNameHttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      },
      isolate: true
    })
```

For non lazy-loaded modules, you can do like

```
    export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
     return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, '/assets/i18n/', '.json');
    }
```

In app.module.ts file :-

```
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      },
      isolate: true
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you have to set default lang ! for example :

```
export class ChildModule {
 constructor(private readonly translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.setDefaultLang(translate.getBrowserLang());
  }
}
```