# ngx-translate not loading for some lazy modules

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I have an Angular application which uses [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) for localization. The only non default setup is I use a custom load which gets my strings from a service. So in my `app.module.ts` I have the following...

```
 TranslateModule.forRoot({     
    loader: { provide: TranslateLoader, useFactory: () => new CustomNgxLoader() },      
    useDefaultLang: false
}),
```

The custom loader is really just a dictionary, ie

```
export class CustomNgxLoader implements TranslateLoader {    
  private static dictionaries: { [key: string]: any; } = {};
  
  public setTranslations(locale: string, translations: any = {}): void {
      
    CustomNgxLoader.dictionaries[locale] = translations;
  }
 
  public getTranslation(locale: string): Observable<any> {
    const dictionary = CustomNgxLoader.dictionaries[locale] || {};
    return of(dictionary);
  }
}
```

I do a call, get the resources and then set via

```
  this.ngxLoader.setTranslations(currentLocale, i18nLookup);
  this.translate.use(currentLocale);
```

I also have a number of lazy loaded modules, and each of these just have the following in the module imports...

```
 TranslateModule.forChild(),
```

I have had this setup since Angular v7, and never had a problem. However, after my last upgrade to Angular `^16.1.3` and `"@ngx-translate/core": "^15.0.0"` I now have most (one works for some reason) no translations. I have translations in a non lazy module, and (bizarrely) in one of the lazy loaded modules.

I have done a simple new test app with the same setup (with a dummy service call), and I get no problems. So I have no idea why this is failing for my production application.

I have tried ideas such as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51302703/ngx-translate-is-not-working-for-lazy-loaded-module), and passing values for isolation etc to fhte `forChild` calls as I have seen in other issues (similar but more complex) on the github page.

As I cannot reproduce in a sample application, I am stuck trying to debug it to find our where it is possibly going wrong.

My only clue so far is putting break point in the `TranslateService` constructor, which seems to be called when we enter each lazy module.

The difference seems to be in what is passed in as the `store` argument.

When I start the application, and a non lazy page is loaded, the first call to the constructor, the `store` properties ate empty...

[image]

Not surprising as I am yet to call `translator.use()`, and my initial non lazy modules is all translated fine. Now I load my first lazy module, the `forChild1()` is called, and in the `TranslateService` constructor, I see the following for the store parameter...

[image]

[image]

And all translations work.

Now I Load the next lazy module, but not in the constructor, the store argument is now empty

[image]

And no I have no translations on that component, I just see the keys.

Also, if I look at `translateService.currentLang` in the components constructor, it is undefined (whereas in the component where translations work, it is set. As per some other suggestions I have also added

```
 const currentLang = translateService.currentLang;
 translateService.currentLang = '';
 translateService.use(currentLang);
```

in the component constructor, but that does not help (I assume the the store has nothing in the collection to load).

I have tries to see where this "store" is instantiated, looking at every point in the call stack,

[image]

I just can't see where the constructor arguments come from.

As I don't get the problem in a simple sample app, I am stuck having to try and work this out in my larger application. The setup is almost stock apart from the custom loader, and I Have never had a problem with this until this latest update.

How can I further debug this? What could be causing this? I am not sure what else to try.

### Update 1

I put a breakpoint in the translate store property initializations, and when I enter the lazy component that is broken, I see a new `TranslateStore` being instantiated..

[image]

In my sample app that works, I do NOT see this called a second time. So for some reason a new `TranslateStore` instance is being created.

Putting in earlier breakpoints, for the second instance, we enter here...

[image]

def = null

And here is where the new TranslateStore is being created....

[image]

Also looking at the source code `translate.store.ts`, `TranslateStore` has no @injectable()

So, now need to know why this is occurring (here and not in my sample app)